# Avoid cache in Cast extension for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, caching, google-chrome-extension, google-cast, chromecast

Is there any way to avoid the cache that the Cast extension for Chrome does? It seems like, when detecting a device, it caches the list and even turning off your TV/Chromecast, the devices are still listed on your extension when clicking the icon on the browser.

It's really weird because website's implementation detects that the Cast extension has listed a device and the possibility to launch an stream is active, but if you try, obviously, it crashes due the device is not really on.

Any way to tell the extension to search always for devices instead of listing its cached ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is also a bug there that we are working on to get fixed; that would address a good portion of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a stale cached device in the list, you can open your Cast extension's background.html page, go to Resources tab, select local storage and the chrome-extension, from there you can delete the

localStorage['mdns.serviceToUse']

this should clear cached devices.

In general there is a tradeoff between caching and performance. Disconnected/powered off devices should disappear fairly quickly.

Comment: That's useful for a developer, but not for a regular user :/